# Fixed position, 100% height element, not always 100% on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I want a 40px, 100% height element that is fixed to the left of my responsive website, obviously I need it to be 100% at all times and it works fine on desktop browsers.

The problem arises when I'm on a mobile browser (nexus 7, Chrome). Keeping your finger pressed on the screen, the 100% height seems to be off by ~10%, until you let go and the element becomes 100% again.

There is a url bar that appears, briefly when scrolling, then disappears I believe it is that which is offsetting the 100% height.

So the problem appears to be Chrome's URL bar and probably other mobile browser URL bars that act in the same way, how do I get around this?

Here's the CSS:

```
div#dummyMenu{
width:40px; 
position:fixed; 
top:0; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
background-color:#444;
}
```

I even threw in some **jQuery** to doubly make sure but still the same problem:

```
jQuery(document).on("scroll",function(){
    var documentHeight = jQuery(document).height();
    jQuery('#dummyMenu').css('height',documentHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`var documentHeight = $(document).height();`

to

`var documentHeight = $(window).innerHeight();`

`window.innerHeight()` returns the height of the window, without `bars` or such from the web browser (the `viewport`).

However, since the scrollbar is interfering, I think you should try `$(window).height` instead.

Also, make sure you included `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your HTML.

I also think the problem may be that you're saying `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: That sounds very logical and likely, let me try it :)

Comment: @UzumakiDev And good thing it's Android, it sometimes doesn't return the right value on Mobile Safari.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Maybe try `jQuery('#dummyMenu').css('height',documentHeight + 'px');`?  Also, make sure you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your HTML.

Comment: aha, I actually had that and deleted it when I was trouble shooting before, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Okay, will include in my answer, and if it works make sure to give me credit by *accepting my answer* :)

Comment: Still the same. Maybe it's my viewport options? `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">` P.S Merry Christmas :D

Comment: @UzumakiDev  Try using `$(window).height()` instead of `$(window).innerHeight()` because there's a difference between `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()`.

Comment: If you have a mobile device at hand you can view it here http://lartmagazine.co.uk/ the left grey bar. p.s oh yea it needs to be in landscape

Comment: @UzumakiDev  I just noticed something, you have `jQuery(document).height();` while it's supposed to be `$(document).height();`.  I also edited my question, it's supposed to be a `$` not `jQuery`.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: I'm afraid still nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Progress; so I attached our jQuery to a floating div instead of a fixed div and it has seemed to have solved the problem.. Now I just have to battle with a z-index and the absolute position' element that is covering the top half of the bar, the reason why I used a fixed element in the first place.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Glad and not glad to hear it.  `position:absolute`: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

Comment: I did move the div elsewhere so it was relative to the wrapper so I thought to check if that was why, changed to `fixed` same problem, back to `absolute` perfect. Neither my body or wrapper have `position:relative;` at the moment.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Did this solve your problem?  If it did, can you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed positions are not widely supported in Mobile Browsers so you'll be forced to use either relative or absolute.

Have a look at this article [here](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/) for a work around and more...

Comment: Aha, yes I see that now, I added my answer a while ago. I thought Mobile Browsers were better at handling fixed positions now though?

Answer (score 0):

I moved my element just after the site wrapper and made it `position:absolute;` instead of fixed.

Not quite sure why it fixed it but it did...

```
div#dummyMenu{
width:40px; 
position:absolute; 
left:0; 
background-color:#444; 
z-index:100; 
height:100%;
}
```

I also added some jQuery, with the help of the comment section.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on("load",function(){ 
        var windowHeight = $(document).height();
        $('#dummyMenu').css('height',windowHeight + 'px');
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowHeight = $(document).height();
        $('#dummyMenu').css('height',windowHeight + 'px');
    });
});
```